# How do pass forms-based authentication form iphone app to website?

Tags: javascript, iphone, authentication, asp.net, fba

I am working on creating an iphone application which logins to we website and retrieves a table, and displays the content within the app. To view the table a Login is required. It seems the site is using Form-Baseds Authentication. [WebSite's Login Screen](http://www.retaillink.wal-mart.com)

So How do I pass the login ID and pass from xcode to the to the site and retain the information so the user only needs to login once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remember the login credentials, the easiest way is to put them into a NSDictionary and write that to the application bundle, then read it later, when needed. Remember to give the users a chance to change their login credentials later on and at least think about encrypting the data.

As to the form-based login, the way to go would be to create a NSURLRequest to the login forms URL, if it is GET-based, simply do it like url.somewhere/form?user=foo&pass=bar, if it is POST-based, alter the created request and include the information needed in the POST-field.